# WEB API Routing with Multiple Get Actions

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am new to WEB API and trying to follow the methodology for routing set up at the site

In my controller I have all standard verb based Actions Get ... Delete.

I also have some other Get Verb based Actions. We register routes  for each controller and below is my route setup.
See Below.  My Actions methods have attributes like below. However when I type in for example `http://server:49279/api/Licenses`
I get error saying MultipleActions match request
   The Actions  Search,SearchByArtistId

Not sure how to handle this when the controller is hard coded

Any help would be valuable as I am not able to find a solution online

Thanks

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs(new string[] { "Get" })]
[System.Web.Http.ActionName("PublishersByLicense")]
public HttpResponseMessage PublishersByLicense(Guid Id)
{
string vControllerName="Licenses";
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute
       (
           name: "PublishersByLicense" + vControllerName,
           routeTemplate: "api/" + vControllerName + "/" + "PublishersByLicense" + "/{aLicenseId}",
           defaults: new
           {
               controller = vControllerName,
               action = "PublishersByLicense"
           },
           constraints: new
           {
               httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get)
           }
        );


            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute
           (
               name: "Search" + vControllerName,
               routeTemplate: "api/" + vControllerName + "/" + "Search" + "/{aTrackIds}",
               defaults: new
               {
                   controller = vControllerName,
                   action = "Search"
               },
               constraints: new
               {
                   httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get)
               }
           );



            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute
            (
                name: "GetAll" + vControllerName,
                routeTemplate: "api/" + vControllerName,
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = vControllerName
                },
                  constraints: new
                  {
                      httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get)
                  }
            );


            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute
           (
               name: "GetSingle" + vControllerName,
               routeTemplate: "api/" + vControllerName + "/{aLicenseId}",
               defaults: new
               {
                   controller = vControllerName
               },
               constraints: new
               {
                   httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get)
               }
           );
```

Here is my Controller Code

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs(new string[] { "Get" })]
[System.Web.Http.ActionName("Search")]
public HttpResponseMessage Search([FromUri]Guid[] aTrackIds)
{
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A request to `http://server:49279/api/Licenses` will be matched by the third route you define:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute
(
    name: "GetAll" + vControllerName,
    routeTemplate: "api/" + vControllerName,
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = vControllerName
    },
    constraints: new
    {
        httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get)
    }
);
```

Since you're not explicitly specifying an `action` route value in it, Web API tries to find the best-fitting action itself.

I don't know your controller code, but I suppose that both `Search` and `SearchByArtistId` have the same number of parameters that can be populated from the request data, thus making them equally good (or bad) action choices. This is why Web API can't unambiguously pick the one right action.

Comment: Hi Marius  Thank you for the answer. I Have added controller code signature for Get and Search in my Question. I could not figure out what route setup would solve my problem. I did look at a few tutorials and samples from the net but those did not help. Do you know of any good resource -especially sample code with multiple Get Actions . Also in our setup controller name is Hard Coded - not as {controller}